# How to build Spring Web MVC on top of Spring Data Rest

Tags: java, angularjs, spring, spring-mvc, tomcat

I have built my application so far using Spring Data REST on top of Spring Data JPA. I want to host my frontend through the Tomcat servlet that's running my Spring backend, but even after doing extensive research, I'm not sure how to proceed. I want to make it annotation-based (avoid xml as much as possible). I have an index.html and angularjs controllers, but I am currently just opening it in the browser, none of my html pages are being served through a server. How do I get started hosting my frontend through Spring and Tomcat. If it helps, this is my Application.java:

```
@EnableWebMvc
@SpringBootApplication // includes @Configuration, @EnableAutoConfiguration, @ComponentScan
@PropertySource(value = "jdbc.properties")
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.ak.repositories")
public class Application extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public Test test(ProductRepository p, ServiceRepository s, PricingModelRepository rp) {
        return new Test(p, s, rp);
    }

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
         registry.addResourceHandler("/css/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:frontend/css/");
}
```

I appreciate any and all help. Thank you!

Comment: check this tutorial, if it help you, i will post it as an answer:



  http://websystique.com/springmvc/spring-mvc-4-angularjs-example/